# Is it possible to use Grub to run an EFI binary?

Tags: grub2, uefi

On an efi system it it possible to run arbitrary efi binaries.

Especially I can use the efi shell (one efi binary) to run grub (another efi binary).

Is it also possible to use grub to run for example an efi shell?

(In theory this should be no problem, but I did not find the correct command to start such a binary.)

Comment: Is that what the `chainloader` command does?

Comment: KeyTool.efi is a nice menu driven launcher for efi-binaries, see my below answer for details.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, and here's a short example taken from Rod Smith's great page on [GRUB 2/EFI Boot Loading](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/grub2.html)

To chainload another EFI boot loader, one uses GRUB2 `chainloader`

The following grub2 menuentry example will run an EFI bootloader

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod chain
        set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Comment: as opposed to hard-coding the drive/partition using set root='', I recommend using: 
`search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <UUID>`
where <UUID> is the output from the _blkid_ command

Answer (score 0):

yes! modify the ARCH-Linux installation ISO-image onto a thumdrive for easy running of all efi that you manage to find or build: see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talk:Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface

**"actually run the *.efi files on a PC"**